# Python: File Reader int and if clauses

Tags: python, linux, file, raspberry-pi, reader

I need some help with Python - I open a file reading its values each line. At the moment my code activates the if part when int(float(line.rstrip())) == 7. But I want to add additional that if the file has no 7 in each line it should run in else.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Sorry for my English.

```
import os
file = open("/home/pi/Desktop/AutoJobs/netdata.py","r")
for line in file:
        if int(float(line.rstrip())) == 7:
                os.system('sudo python /home/pi/Desktop/AutoJobs/tvOn.py')
file.close()
```

/home/pi/Desktop/AutoJobs/netdata.py:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

(The numbers are the last part of my devices in network (192.168.1.X) and I want to switch off when device .7 is not connected - the file netdata.py gets updated every minute and it could happen that for example device .7 is not connected and the number 7 is not listed in the file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
found =False
file = open("/home/pi/Desktop/AutoJobs/netdata.py","r")
for line in file:
        if int(float(line.rstrip())) == 7:
                found = True
                os.system('sudo python /home/pi/Desktop/AutoJobs/tvOn.py')
file.close()
if not found:
        print "Add your code here."
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
import os
with open("/home/pi/Desktop/AutoJobs/netdata.py","r") as f
    no_seven = True
    for line in f:
        if int(float(line.rstrip())) == 7:
            os.system('sudo python /home/pi/Desktop/AutoJobs/tvOn.py')
            no_seven = False
    if no_seven:
        print("no seven")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help - but may I ask you one question? I am not sure but I think something is missing here:

if no_seven:

if no_seven = true: (Or am I  wrong?)

Sorry for my English.

Comment: It is half past midnight and I'm in front of Belgian bear after a cocktail... in python say `if no_seven` is the same of say `if no_seven==True` or `if no_seven is True`

Comment: Enjoy! I will try both! Thanks sir.